# Jolt without specification file

Tags: java, jolt

I am trying to transform json using Jolt. can we remove specification file from Jolt ? is any alternative is available ? my requirement is to use java Map.

Comment: "use java map" is a very broad requirement. Do you need any transformation at all?

Comment: Yes, I want to transform json one format to another. when I am using Java map for transformation without jolt, it is very complicated So I tried to use Jolt API, but my requirement is we are getting request json path and response json path in map. is there any alternative in Jolt without spec file.

Comment: The question doesn't appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have to use specification file in Jolt to provide mapping from request JSON to Response JSON. So as of my R&D I reach my point we can't work without specification file in jolt.

Awesome API is provided by JOLT to transform JSON. thanks JOLT